Do "peaceable journey" laws apply to things other than firearms?
In the United States, the Firearm Owners Protection Act has a "Safe Passage" provision that allows you transport firearms through states where you do not have a permit as long as the firearms are not readily accessible. Does this or a similar law apply to things that aren't guns?
For example, California only allows "safe and sane" fireworks, or those that do not leave the ground or explode. However, nearly all types of consumer fireworks are legal in Nevada. Police in California are known to set up checkpoints near the border so they could confiscate unapproved fireworks that enter the state.
If someone bringing in fireworks from Nevada crosses a checkpoint in California and gets pulled over, but says they are transporting the fireworks to Washington (another state that allows nearly all fireworks), then would they be free to go?
I asked this question on a now-defunct fireworks forum years ago, and the answer was a resounding "yes." However, no one who replied to me actually provided a source or cited specific laws. I did some Googling and could not find any mention of a "peaceable journey" law that does not apply specifically to guns.

There must be some carve-out for people employed by freight and package companies, though I don't know what particular law protects them. They transport controlled substances without a prescription; they transport restricted equipment that requires a license such as X-ray machines, pesticides that require a license, and so on. Never heard of a UPS truck being pulled over at the California border by agents looking for DDT.

@MTA I suspect they do have specific permits. When I shipped something like that it was in a special clearly marked packaging and not the regular UPS box. They also ask whether any control substances are in packages (same with USPS).

Transportation and shipping companies hold special transport-only licenses, and there is dangerous cargo qualifications for drivers. Some goods are road-banned but for the last miles and require train shipping for safety reasons...

The second amendment doesn't apply to fireworks, and they're not considered firearms. In California, possession of dangerous fireworks is forbidden (see CA Health & Safety Code § 12677 (2023)):

It is unlawful for any person to possess dangerous fireworks without holding a valid permit.

So the answer is likely "no".

I'm more interested in the general case of something being legal in one state but illegal in another, not fireworks in particular. I only used fireworks as an example.

@Danny then that’s what you should have asked. This appears to be an accurate reflection of California law. Weapons are special because they have Constitutional protection, most other things don’t.

@Danny There is no general right to transport things that are illegal in one state but legal in another across a state where it is illegal. This is why the Firearms Protection Act was enacted. There are arguably dormant commerce clause considerations under the U.S. Constitution and there may be specific cases where transport is allowed (e.g. by state or federal law). But the broader, general question doesn't have a general answer in U.S. law.

That's fair. It seems the answer for things other than firearms is "no" then. I wish I knew the importance of sourcing information back then.

@Danny provocative example: drugs. Just because pot might be legal in Canada and a non bordering state does not make transport from Canada to there through a banning state legal.
